# Encode/decode Base64 fails

Tags: java, android, utf-8, base64

in my application client-server, on client side I send the file content in following format:

```
public static String getImageFromURI (Context contesto, Uri uri) {
    InputStream is;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos;
    try {
        is = contesto.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        try {
            for (int readNum; (readNum = is.read(buf)) != -1;) {
                bos.write(buf, 0, readNum); //no doubt here is 0
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.d("TAG_F2S", "Sono nel catch IOExcetion con emssage = " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        return new String (Base64.encode(bos.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT), "UTF-8");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        Log.d("TAG_F2S", "Sono nel catch FileNotFoundExcetion con emssage = " + fnfe.getMessage());
        fnfe.printStackTrace();

        return null;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
        Log.d("TAG_F2S", "Sono nel catch UnsupportedEncodingExcetion con emssage = " + uee.getMessage());
        uee.printStackTrace();

        return null;
    }
}
```

and on server side I try to create the file as follow:

```
byte [] byteFile = java.util.Base64.getDecoder ().decode(contenuto.getBytes("UTF-8"));

Files.write(Paths.get(myPath), byteFile);
```

But I can't obtain the result cause the exception like this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character a
at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Unknown Source)
....
```

What's my error? I don't understand..
Thanks for your help.

---

EDIT:
The String that i send to the server is the following:
https://codeshare.io/GqQWNA

Comment: I wonder, what does `contenuto.getBytes("UTF-8")` return in your example?

Comment: What is the string it's trying to decode when failing?

Comment: @GregT I edited my post

Comment: @AndreasHartmann see my edit, thanks

Comment: Thanks! It's a bit huge, though. Please find the minimal part of Base64 code that still throws this exception. Also it contains whitespaces, which I think it shouldn't.

Comment: @GregT, the exception go when i try to decode in Base64, on server side.
Yes, i can see the whitespaces, but it's the process that insert these spaces..
If this process is wrong, how i would to send my file to the server? (please exclude all the option different by POST request)

Comment: @ClaudioP sorry I don't know about sending it to the server, but I have some experience in decoding. By "process" do you mean your program or codeshare? Can you send us a very short string that fails?

Comment: Are you sure that's base64? Trying to decode it with an online decoder results in a corrupted file

Comment: @AndreasHartmann the code was not properly formatted, my solution is below.

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem:

when I encode the file content and I send data to the server in POST request, the content is modified replacing alland only '+' characters with ' ' (whitespace).
Operating the following action on server side:

```
java.util.Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(contenuto.replace(" ", "+"));
```

I don't have the problem. Note that i used **getMimeDecoder and not getDecoder**, otherwise it doesn't work.

Does anyone know the reason for this problem?

Comment: My two cents: getDecoder() will error out if the content has characters outside its allowed set in RFC 4648(https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648#section-5). If the content has characters such as carriage return/line feed as posted in the question (https://codeshare.io/GqQWNA), it will fail. getMimeDecoder() takes care of carriage return and line feed as mentioned in RFC 2045(https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2045#section-2.1)

Comment: Great, that's a really tricky one! I had this issue trying to parse Kubernetes API